# How to get out of this nightmare situation with Paypal?

Tags: paypal

On May 31st, 2020 I got a number of notifications on my Facebook account from Paypal account stating purchases were made from my UPS account. I promptly reported this to Paypal and UPS. Both of them started telling I need to contact the other party. I did and told both of them that of this problem. However, on Jun 10th I was charged for 14 of the transactions. I disputed these transactions and was refunded. I removed UPS from my automatic payment . However, on Jun 11th I was charged again. I promptly disputed but this time they said it was authorized and refused to refund. All these transactions are of the same nature and same amount. I am unable to close my account because of the 'Pending' transactions which Paypal refuses to unauthorize and at the same time Paypal refuses to let me close my account due to Pending transactions. Can I go to my Bank and ask them to blacklist Paypal so that money doesn't get taken out?

Comment: What's the method of payment? Credit card or ACH?

Comment: It was debited from my bank account. Is that ACH?

Comment: Yes. ACH transactions are notoriously hard to dispute. Talk to your bank's Fraud department. Make it very clear that you do not recognize these transactions and they are fraudulent. They may require you to file a police report. It seems that perhaps your Paypal, Facebook, and/or your UPS accounts have been hacked. Change all your passwords ASAP to something hard to guess.